# Regex convert [quote="author"]text[/quote] to a formatted div block

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to convert `[quote="author"]text[/quote]` into a formatted div block.

```
function bbCode($p_text){

      // capture author

      $pattern = '/\[quote="(.+)"\]/';
      preg_match($pattern, $p_text, $match);

      // replace bbcode with formatted block

      $patternA = '/\[quote=".+"\]/'; // captures [quote="..."]
      $replacementA = '</p><div class="quote"><strong class="quote-author"><?php echo $match; ?> wrote:</strong><br>';
      $p_text = preg_replace($patternA, $replacementA, $p_text);

      $patternB = '/\[\/quote\]/'; // captures [/quote]
      $replacementB = '</div><p class="thread-p">';
      $p_text = preg_replace($patternB, $replacementB, $p_text);

      return $p_text;

}
```

In the main file:

```
<?php 

// $p_text is defined before this
$p_text = bbCode($p_text); 

?>

<p class="thread-p"><?php echo $p_text; ?></p>
```

It seems to be just coming up with `[quote="author"]text` then the div closes some other section of the html below. Not sure what I've done wrong.

I've tried to end the `<p>` because divs can't go inside `<p>`'s iirc, maybe that's messing something up?

Comment: Please try my library for parsing shortcodes and BBCodes: github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . If you need more information, submit an issue and I'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question to be that you would like to take

> [quote="author"]text[/quote]

and create HTML which will display the author and text.

This is one possible implementation:

```
<?php
function bbCode($p_text) {
        $pattern = '#\[quote="([^\"]+)"\]([^\[]+)\[/quote\]#';
        preg_match_all($pattern,$p_text,$matches);
        $html = <<< HTML
<div class="quote">
        <span class="quote-author">__AUTHOR__ wrote:</span>
        <p>__QUOTE__</p>
</div>
HTML;
        return str_replace(['__AUTHOR__','__QUOTE__'],[$matches[1][0],$matches[2][0]], $html);

}
echo bbCode('[quote="author"]text[/quote]');
```